# Xcode - Simulator - pushnotification

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I have a code working with the push notification but I want to start to debug some functionality over my code and will prefer to have running in the simulator, my question is

How can I tell the xcode to ignore the didregisterForRemote....

Something that I could comment and play on that basis ?

Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {
    NSString *device_token =[[[[deviceToken description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<"withString:@""]
                                                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""]
                                                          stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString: @" " withString: @""];
    [self checkUUID];
    Authentication *auth = [[Authentication alloc] initWithObject];
    int erro = [auth insertDeviceInfo:device_token];

    UINavigationController *navigationController = [self customizedNavigationController];
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.viewController.erro = erro;
    [navigationController setViewControllers: [NSArray arrayWithObject: self.viewController]];
    [self setNavigationController:navigationController];

    [self.window setRootViewController: navigationController];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

I just want to be able to use the simulator to be able to move with my debug

Comment: I want to ignore the pushregistration

Answer (score 3):

best way is use macro `TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR`

```
#if !(TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR)
 NSLog(@"this is only real device code");
#endif
```

Comment: @user1634153: you simply envelop the code you want to exclude from the build when building for simulator between these lines - there can be more of them...

Comment: @user1634153 is will be better to bit adjust app logic and move you code from this method to `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve that using coding then use below condition in your

> didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:

method for ignoring such functionality on simulator:

> -(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
>   {
>
> ```
>  if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) 
>  {
>     //device is simulator
>  }
>  else
>  {
>    //Actual Device
>  }
> ```
>
> }

Comment: Thanks, but where before the didRegeisterFor like
if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {
        //device is simulator
}
else{
      didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:
}

Comment: No inside the didRegisterForRemoteNotification: like this :

- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken {

if ([model isEqualToString:@"iPhone Simulator"]) {
        //device is simulator
}
else{
       //Actual Device
}

}


Check my Edited Answer.